# Getting RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded with angularjs filter

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I am getting **RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded** with filter option in angularjs array of objects.  Without filte option , its working fine.

HTML :

```
  <div class="searchBar">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" ng-model="searchPayment">
    <i class="fa fa-search fa-2x"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="payment col-xs-12" ng-repeat="payment in payments | filter:{ 'name':searchPayment}">
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <div class="section">
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="payment.checked">
            <h5>[[payment.name]]</h5>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and controllrt.js :

```
$scope.payments = [{
  "collection": "105.00",
  "customerEmail": "rk@gmail.com",
  "date": "10\/7\/2016 12:00:00 AM",
  "lan": "JAX15E0140",
  "name": "Rrts",
  "passThru": "105.00",
  "passThruId": "7357ac197",
  "recovery": "0.00",
  "source": "APTA",
  "status": "0"
}, {
  "collection": "6000.00",
  "customerEmail": "tlt@gmail.com",
  "date": "12\/7\/2016 12:00:00 AM",
  "lan": "JAI47",
  "name": "Test23:41:40.635",
  "passThru": "6000.00",
  "passThruId": "6f96d57eca9b9",
  "recovery": "0.00",
  "source": "ABA",
  "status": "0"
}, {
  "collection": "1.50",
  "customerEmail": "me@gmail.com",
  "date": "12\/17\/2015 12:00:00 AM",
  "lan": "H132",
  "name": "REPOT",
  "passThru": "0.00",
  "passThruId": "fbc51ae681c96",
  "recovery": "400.00",
  "source": "ABHTA",
  "status": "0"
}, {
  "collection": "2500.00",
  "customerEmail": "t.e@gmail.com",
  "date": "12\/18\/2016 12:00:00 AM",
  "lan": "JAI1551",
  "name": "Test I55.559",
  "passThru": "2500.00",
  "passThruId": "4beb3ad2c176e3bd",
  "recovery": "0.00",
  "source": "ABTA",
  "status": "0"
}, {
  "collection": "3500.00",
  "customerEmail": "tt@gmail.com",
  "date": "12\/18\/2016 12:00:00 AM",
  "lan": "JAI1",
  "name": "Test Indust:55.559",
  "passThru": "3500.00",
  "passThruId": "edb23c1e305550",
  "recovery": "0.00",
  "source": "AA",
  "status": "0"
}]
```

This is what getting in console. Can anyone help to remove this error while using filter option ?
 [image]

Comment: `filter:{ 'name':searchPayment}` is creating some sort of infinite loop.. try to filter data in controller and check array size returned...

Comment: @atulquest93 :  Tried with this in conreoller $scope.$watch('searchPayment', function(oldVal, newVal) {
        // console.log("oldVal, newVal", oldVal, newVal);
        if (oldVal != newVal) {
            console.log($scope.payments);
            $scope.payments = $filter('filter')($scope.payments, newVal);
            // console.log($scope.payments);
        }

    });

Comment: on entering 2nd character giving me same  number number of array as that of with 1st character with same error